# Netlogo : change patch color of one patch if orthogonal neighbors have the same color

Tags: patch, netlogo

I'm new to netlogo and I need some help.

I am trying to grow a continuous patch of one color (green on a black background). However, I will sometimes have a black patch that is completely surrounded by green patches. I would like to change the color of those black patches to green.

I tried :

```
ask patches [
    if neighbors4 with [pcolor = 55] 
    [set pcolor 55]
  ]
```

but it gives me an error, as does

```
ask patches [
    if any? neighbors4 [pcolor = 55] 
    [set pcolor 55]
  ]
```

Here is the code that works that will sometimes leave black patches surrounded by green patches :

```
to setup
  clear-all
  set-patch-size 4
  resize-world -50 50 -50 50
  ask patches[set pcolor black]
  grow-cell
  reset-ticks
end

to grow-cell
    ask patch 0 0 [ 
    set pcolor 55
    ask neighbors [ 
    set pcolor 55
    ]
  ]
  repeat 45 
  [ ask patches with [pcolor = black]
    [ set pcolor [pcolor] of one-of neighbors4 ] ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly/barely clever hack.

```
Ask patches[
   if mean [pcolor] of neighbors4 = green[set pcolor green]
]
```

Or alternately:

```
Ask patches with [ count neighbors4 with [pcolor = green] = 4 ]
[set pcolor green]
```